# php mysql timestamp works only on update

Tags: php, mysql

i am using a timestamp type column in my mysql database, and i have enabled the option for auto update timestamp, but the time stamp works only on update command and not on insert

i am using navicat mysql client

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have checked by adding now() to default value but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the **current timestamp** as the default value along with enabling auto-update. That should work for you.
See: [current_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp)

Did you mean something like this..

Comment: i have tried current timestamp but mysql says invalid default value

Comment: you can use NOW() as the value

Answer (score 0):

To set the TIMESTAMP column in either table to the current timestamp at insert time, explicitly assign it that value.

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (NOW());
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the column default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

If you are using a server side language to insert data into the table, you could simply insert the current date into that column. In PHP, for example, that would be

```
<?php
$time = time();
?>
```